# "Waiter's paradox" - what's wrong with this reasoning?

Tags: paradoxes

Here's a puzzle I just heard and while I know that this reasoning is fundamentally wrong, I can't explain why:

1. Three people bought a dish for, say, 25\$ and paid 30\$
2. The waiter didn't want to divide 5 by 3, so he took 2\$ for himself and gave 1$ to each of the clients
3. Each of them seems to have spent 9\$, but 9\$ x 3 = 27\$, not 28. What happened to this one dollar?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_dollar_riddle

Comment: @AlexR. I wish you posted the link as an answer, I would have accepted it.

Comment: More duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656047/where-is-the-lost-dollar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656047/where-is-the-lost-dollar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480195/general-and-simple-math-problem

Answer (score 0):

Expenditure of customers:
$$
30 \text{ (initial payment})-\color{green}{3} \text{ (change})=\color{teal}{27}.
$$
Income of restaurant:
$$
30-\color{red}{2} \text{ (waiter's stolen amount})-\color{green}{3}\text{ (change to customers})=\color{blue}{25}.
$$
Income of waiter:
$$
\color{red}{2},
$$
which is just the amount he stole.

Total income $=\color{red}{2}+\color{blue}{25}=\color{teal}{27}=$ total expenditure. So no inconsistency here.